# How to hide a div if it doesn't contain a table inside it

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a `div` like this:

```
<div class="EventsRollup">
    <span class="EventsRollupTitle">Health Lecture Events</span>
    <!--this is where a table would be dynamically inserted by sharepoint 
        based on some filter, if filter is true, a tabel will get in there, 
        else not-->
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how do I hide the whole `div` if no `table` was inserted because the `div` has background color and the empty background color shows with no `table` contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.EventsRollup').not(':has(table)').hide();
```

or

```
$('.EventsRollup:not(:has(table))').hide();
```

Comment: it works but it does display the div for like a quick sec and then hides it making the page to flash.. how to prevent that?

Comment: @AnjuThapa, just hide it by default using some CSS. `display: none;`

Comment: @AnjuThapa: Xeon06 is right. You'd be better off hiding all the `.EventsRollup` elements in CSS, then showing the ones that *have* a table. `$('.EventsRollup').has('table').show()` or `$('.EventsRollup:has(table)').show()`

Comment: how do you do use CSS in jquery??

Comment: @AnjuThapa: The point is that you do it in your stylesheet. You're using stylesheets, right?

Comment: Yea i am using CSS but only those EventsRollUp divs will hide that wont have a table inside them. How do you sort the ones that do and that dont in CSS?

Comment: @AnjuThapa: In CSS do `.EventsRollup { display:none; }`, then with jQuery, use the code I posted in the comment above: `$('.EventsRollup').has('table').show()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('.EventsRollup').find('table').length === 0) {
    $('.EventsRollup').hide();
}
```

This assumes there is only one `.EventsRollup`... If there are more, you could use a loop...

```
$('.EventsRollup').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('table').length === 0) {
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to hide it if it *doesn't* contain a table. Don't you want `==` instead of `>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery( ".EventsRollup").filter( function(){
return !this.getElementsByTagName("table").length;
}).hide();
```